# Is there a well known name for this surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Is there a classification that exists for a surface of the following form?

$${\frac {{x}^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {{y}^{2}}{
 \left( {y}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}={\frac {{z}^{2}}{ \left( {z}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}$$

The expression seems simple enough, but wolfram alpha's website chokes on it, and refused to plot it for me online.

Maple gave me this, when plotting on the interval -1..1 for each of x,y,and z:[image: Expression plot]

Although that didn't help me figure out what the name of the surface was, or if it even has a name.

Comment: I'm curious - did you write down these equations because of their symmetry or do you have some application in mind? (The locus you've drawn is certainly very pretty.)

Comment: It started out as just an idle experiment that was a variation on an infinite cone, and now it's got me quite puzzled.  It seems to me that something that can be described with such a symmetric equation should have a common name, but I can't figure oiut what it is.